# How to catch text from string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Here, Im trying to get the middle value (**log in**) of the string in **Comment column** and then get the count for each user. but I think this is not the right way to do. Is there any other way you guys have...!

```
user#   user ID Comments
101     user 1  ***log in*** : shera
101     user 1  ***log in*** : Mark
102     user 2  ***log out***
105     user 5  ***log in*** : Mark
104     user 4  ***ideal***
103     user 3  ***ideal***
101     user 1  ***ideal***
102     user 2  ***log out*** : since 5 mnt
105     user 5  ***log in*** : Mark
104     user 4  ***ideal***
103     user 3  ***log out***
```

query need to be design for:

```
         log in ideal   log out
user 1    2       0        3
user 2    0       2        5
user 5    0       2        1
          ------------------
Total      2      4        9
```

Thanks for consideration.
Jay

Comment: Are there always three `*` between the middle value?

Comment: yes it is. Its like (***log in***).

Comment: And do you want the result to be in columns or in rows? That is, `user1 login 2`, `user1 ideal 0`, `user2 login 0`, etc.

Comment: exactly Joao, I just want create report each day that How many user log in or log out for a day. And cumulative total of all user at the end of table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most optimized way, but if your table name is `comments` (or adjust below as needed):

```
SELECT user, IFNULL(login,0) as login, IFNULL(ideal,0) as ideal,
       IFNULL(logout,0) as logout
FROM (
 SELECT userid, user
 FROM comments
 GROUP BY userid
) c
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT userid, count(userid) AS login
 FROM comments
 WHERE comment LIKE '%log in%'
 GROUP BY userid
) c1 ON c.userid=c1.userid
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT userid, count(userid) AS logout
 FROM comments
 WHERE comment LIKE '%log out%'
 GROUP BY userid
) c2 ON c.userid=c2.userid
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT userid, count(userid) AS ideal
 FROM comments
 WHERE comment LIKE '%ideal%'
 GROUP BY userid
) c3 ON c.userid=c3.userid
```

Comment: Thanks JScoobyCed. Let me try.

Comment: Its saya error near where clause....: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE comment LIKE '%log in%' )

Comment: I updated. Sorry it's been a long day for me :) Need to put the `GROUP BY` at the end of each sub-query, not before the `WHERE`

Comment: no problem. Im really appreciate you for help. I run the query this time and its run fine, but I get multiple entry of user in table. I use GROUP function at the end of query, but it show me wrong result. I edit the query. just check it. Thanks

Comment: I don't see your edit. But I think I see the issue. See my edit to make he many records of comments to be unique.

Comment: Ya I guess. But different team leader put their name after comments. So can we make it unique we can fetch unique row.

Comment: Did try the query? It is making the rows unique based on `userid`, not based on `comments` comment. My previous comment should have said `See my edit to make the many records of comments to be unique by grouping by userid.`

Comment: I understand what you said. Let me show the result result of your query which is posted after your code. See there is a duplicate row fetched.

Comment: Interesting. Can you post the exact query as you run it in your DB, and eventually the full set of data, if it is not an issue with your company. If so please use a site like pastebin.com and post the link here.

Comment: This is a private pastebin, only you can view it.

Comment: Even I cant find it. sorry about that. I really need help for this problem. any way this is the link that lead you to the real data. Thanks for all your effort. Really appreciated. http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=cCkXAXwt

Comment: Umm... it seems your only distinct data is 'clientName', so I guess you need to JOIN the four queries (accepted, cancelled, noshow and flagged) using clientName as join key.